# Oracle - MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE in logfile name

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

I'm creating a `data guard` using hot backup from the primary server.
In my restore I've used the following commands to restore:

```
run{
set newname for database to '+DADOS';
restore database;
switch datafile all;
switch tempfile all;
recover database;
}
```

After successful restore and recovery my redo logfile names has the name below:

```
select member from v$logfile;

+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_1.4294967295.4294967295
+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_1.287.1040583755
+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_2.4294967295.4294967295
+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_3.4294967295.4294967295
+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_3.259.1036639239
+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_4.4294967295.4294967295
+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_2.288.1040583761
+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_5.4294967295.4294967295
+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_5.295.1042634101
+DADOS/MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_6.4294967295.4294967295
+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_6.297.1042634113
```

Why they have the "MUST_RENAME_THIS_LOGFILE_"? isn't automatic?

In my standby I'm using the `db_log_file_name_convert` and `log_file_name_convert`

```
log_file_name_convert = +DATA, +DADOS
db_file_name_convert = +DATA, +DADOS
```

Other issue is that some tempfiles come just with the DG name (see last line below).

```
select name from v$datafile union all select name from v$tempfile;

+DADOS/MOOTSTB/DATAFILE/system.266.1042731967
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/DATAFILE/sysaux.292.1042731967
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249914E10CA3494E0532900A8C0EAA4/DATAFILE/system.278.1042732081
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249914E10CA3494E0532900A8C0EAA4/DATAFILE/sysaux.296.1042732081
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/DATAFILE/users.309.1042731967
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249914E10CA3494E0532900A8C0EAA4/DATAFILE/undotbs1.320.1042732081
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/DATAFILE/undotbs2.283.1042731967
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/system.257.1042731811
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/sysaux.284.1042731809
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/undotbs1.289.1042731811
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/users.267.1042731811
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/soe.311.1042731809
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/teste.308.1042731811
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249E748BB047773E0532900A8C02088/DATAFILE/undo_2.304.1042731811
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/DATAFILE/undotbs1.302.1042731967
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/TEMPFILE/temp.319.1042736311
+DADOS/MOOTSTB/A249914E10CA3494E0532900A8C0EAA4/TEMPFILE/temp.318.1042736323
+DADOS  <<<<<< is a tempfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore + recovery from backup does not use online redo logs. Your redo logs were just named something, but those files do not exist yet. A physical standby database also does not use online redo logs (it uses standby redo logs).

The redo log groups will be automatically cleared (rename according to OMF + create the file) whenever they are needed the first time. Like when you actually open the database in `READ WRITE` mode after converting the physical standby into a primary database or snapshot standby or logical standby.

`+FRA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_1.287.1040583755` is also incorrect. At this point that file does not exist and the location of that file, once cleared, will be `+FRA/MOOTSTB/ONLINELOG/...` as the `db_unique_name` on the standby site is `MOOTSTB`. (Assuming you have an FRA diskgroup there.)

With the `db_create_file_dest`, `db_create_online_log_dest_N`, `db_recovery_file_dest` parameters set properly, you can simply clear the logfile groups manually (what would be done automatically anyway when required), so they will be named and placed correctly:

```
alter database clear logfile group 1;
alter database clear logfile group 2;
alter database clear logfile group 3;
alter database clear logfile group 4;
alter database clear logfile group 5;
alter database clear logfile group 6;
```

The tempfile named `+DADOS` is also not a problem. A physical standby in mount stage does not require a tempfile. The tempfile will be automatically renamed and created once the database is opened.

Comment: Thank you!! I've configured the db_create_online_log_dest_N as said and after issue the command "alter database clear logfile group" worked perfectly